# Replacing AJAX calls with a better solution on a monitoring page

Tags: php, ajax, node.js, laravel, websocket

**The Problem**

I have developed a fairly intricate project that uses PHP and Laravel as a back-end. Users of the site mark available or unavailable to respond to calls (as in dispatches) and calls are stored in a MySQL table. Right now, the whole operation is run on a shared web host with Laravel 4 handling the site and incoming data (such as Twilio and Iron.io push queues).

The client wants to show the status of the system on a monitor in their office - a computer and TV monitor have been dedicated to this. The system needs to be realtime or as close as possible, displaying who is available and any ongoing calls. There will be no user interaction with this aspect at all - it just sits there all day displaying data.

Right now, I am simply using AJAX to request JSON every six seconds on a page hosted on their website. Their network has not appreciated this and I am guessing our shared hosting environment probably won't like it in the long run. What I need is some way to send data directly to that computer and have it display on the page ONLY when something changes and without any user interaction client side.
Here is the flow of what I am looking for -

1. User updates their status (ie, available or unavailable),
2. Laravel 4 back-end receives the request (from one of three possible ways using POST data), stores it in the database,
3. Client computer receives this new information and displays it in an HTML table

**Solutions I have thought of**

Node.js is installed on the client computer and Socket.io looks promising for receiving push data. However, I cannot quite piece together how to go about sending data from the PHP Laravel 4 server side to the client side only when something happens (a user's status changes, a call is added to the system).

I can only seem to find information on websockets that handles something like a chat room - this is more of a "sit around for hours until something happens" deal with the need to pull data from MySQL and push it out.

I also thought of setting up a websocket server on Heroku and then sending data from there to the client - but again I am getting a bit stuck on just how to accomplish sending data only when something changes on the database (i.e., Laravel receives POST data and then does something with it).

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think I may have just found the solution for this particular application - Pusher.com. Just stumbled upon it and it looks very promising. Quick install on the shared host with Composer, then a simple API call to them. The client connects to their Activity websocket and receives the data. Fingers crossed!

Comment: Yeah, that looks really promising! Hopefully it's free for the amount of traffic you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done and done! Pusher.com turned out to be exactly what I needed, within a few minutes I transitioned over to it - problem completely solved. Fortunately this is a very low activity project, one connection (max I can ever imagine would be three) and only a couple dozen pushes per day (if that). Well below their free sandbox limits.

The boss will be so pleased. ;) Thanks for the answers, I've learned a lot about websockets today!

Comment: Awesome! If this is how you solved the problem, make sure to mark your answer as correct so that if people land here in the future they will know. Good work : )

Answer (score 2):

I think websockets are definitely the way to go. Node is quite good with handling websockets, but no reason to rewrite your app, you can use websockets with php. I'd check out PHP websockets libraries like [this one](http://socketo.me) for integration.

The general idea with websockets is that rather than connecting to the server, having the server transfer data, then ending the connection, with websockets you keep the connection alive, and there is a javascript interface to receive messages sent from the server even after the page has been loaded. So on a high level, what you would do would be create a page that shows system status, and have that page's javascript hook up to a websockets connection that you'd build into your app. Then within your app's architecture, you would send events through websockets when something happens like a user updating their status, and the page would reeive that event and display it in real time.

I am far from an expert in PHP, so I can't be a lot of help as far as specific implementation details, but hopefully this and the link the the php websockets library will get you on the right path. It seems like they have [really nice docs](http://socketo.me/docs/) which should help guide you along the way. I can assure you that using sockets for this is the way to go, and will be a lot better of a solution than polling.

EDIT: [This library](https://github.com/sidneywidmer/Latchet) also might be of interest to you, although it doesn't look like it's super stable yet.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that library will come in handy down the road